TS2339: Error extending Express Request (e.g. req.payload)
I am currently migrating a Express app to TypeScript.
I have some middleware that needs to store info in the request object (e.g. req.payload) but I keep getting an error.
Here's a simplified version of my code:
// server.ts

import { Application } from 'express';
import { Request, Response, NextFunction } from 'express';

import express from 'express';
const app: Application = express();

function middleware1(req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) {
  req.payload = {
    name: 'bob',
  };

  next();
}

app.use(middleware1);

app.get('/', (req, res, next) => {
  res.json({ message: 'hello world' });
});

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5005;

app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Server listening on port http://localhost:${PORT}`);
});


If I try to store something in req.payload, TypeScript will complain:
Property 'payload' does not exist on type 'Request<ParamsDictionary, any, any, ParsedQs, Record<string, any>>'.(2339)

so I'm trying to extend the Request interface from Express by following this article.
I have created the file @types/express/index.d.ts with the following content:
// @types/express/index.d.ts

declare global {
  namespace Express {
    interface Request {
      payload?: {};
    }
  }
}


And I've updated tsconfig.json to include the following:

// tsconfig.json

// ...

    "typeRoots": [
      "@types",
      "./node_modules/@types"
    ]


I've tried multiple configurations in the declaration file and in tsconfig.json; however, I keep getting the same error.
Is there any other step needed?
Here's a simplified version of the code on StackBlitz

I dont know about the global, and also you need to declare namespace I think. So this should work:
@types/express/index.d.ts:
declare namespace Express {
  interface Request {
    payload?: {};
  }
}


For ts-node, you may also need to add the property "files" to tsconfig.json:
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    //...
  },
  "files": ["src/@types/express/index.d.ts"]
}

Here's a link to stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-d48bzi?file=src%2F%40types%2Fexpress%2Findex.d.ts,src%2Fserver.ts

thanks a lot Max, unfortunately, the compiler keeps giving the same error :s

it seems to work okay in the stackblitz, so there may be some other factors. Did you set up the stackblitz with similar settings as your working environment?

both have similar settings. In both of them (stackblitz and my dev environment), when I run the app with npm run dev the compiler gives the same error.

yea, tsc works fine though, so the actual compiling from ts works. Just ts-node having some issues which is why npm exec ts-node server throws errors.

In my experience ts-node is great for how useful it is but often have issues with it, in this case adding   "files": ["src/@types/express/index.d.ts"] to tsconfig seems to make it work with ts-node also. The stackblitz should be updated to reflect that

I'll update answer too if useful for anyone who finds this
